# Cannot create java class file in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Sorry for this dumb question but i cannot create a new java class file inside my package. Are there any limitations in the deep of packages?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Choose `new` -> `File`. Enter valid name, press enter. In the upcoming dialog choose `Java Class`

Answer (score 0):

I had to right-click on `root/app/src/main/java`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you've opened the project directory correctly.
The Directory that you open as project should have the gradlew batch file, your project iml file etc.
For me, I was trying to open it from a parent directory above the project directory and I was seeing the same issue.